# Proof Inviscid Burgers equation is hyperbolic

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I'm having problems classifying the inviscid burgers equation into elliptic, parabolic or hyperbolic:

> $u_t+uu_x=f(x,t)$

Since the classification for 2nd order partial differential equations of the form:

> $a_{11}(x,y)u_{xx}(x,y) + 2a_{12}(x,y)u_{xy}(x,y)+a_{22}(x,y)u_{yy}(x,y) + b_{1}(x,y)u_{x}(x,y) + b_{2}(x,y)u_{y}(x,y) + c(x,y)u(x,y) = d(x,y)$

takes place defining:

> $\Delta=a_{12}^2-a_{11}a_{22}$

And studying its sign so:

> $\Delta=0 \to$ parabolic equation
>   $\Delta>0 \to$ hyperbolic equation
>   $\Delta<0 \to$ elliptic equation

I guessed this equation would be parabolic since there aren't any second order derivatives so:

> $a_{11}=a_{12}=a_{22}=0$

But checking in the internet it is said to be a hyperbolic equation, and I don't have a clue why it is that way.

Can someone help me?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is of the first order. You cannot use the second order condition to check whether it is hyperbolic/parabolic/elliptic.

You can read about the classification of first order equations/systems in this pdf:

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=2ahUKEwjGnO_I4JngAhWTHDQIHWy2DE4QFjAEegQIBRAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpeople.3sr-grenoble.fr%2Fusers%2Fbloret%2Fenseee%2Fmaths%2Fenseee-maths-IBVPs-3.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3iWOWyyz7PyfihM3IzGIxH